# Can i host java spring based website on cloud

Tags: java, spring, cloud

i don't much about cloud hosting.

Now i am building the website in java using spring , mysql.
Can i host that website on cloud with google or any other provider.
i want to know how much it costs , currently for VPS its about $80 per month

or i have to get the VPS.

I am in Australia

Comment: Costs are off-topic for StackOverflow and this question may not make it as a result.  I can tell you, technology-wise, that Spring can be hosted on a cloud.  Typically to use a cloud you have to conform to their structure.  For example, if you were to use the google cloud (Google App Engine) you couldn't use MySQL, you'd have to use the Google Datastore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. Both on Google App Engine and on Amazon EC2. GAE will impose some limitations, while on EC2 you can deploy as if on VPS.

Comment: i think Amazon is not available in Australia

Comment: there aren't servers in Australia, but you can have an account.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are not limited geographically if you want to use cloud service.
From my perspective you should pay your attention on several cloud computing platforms which meet your requirements:

[Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/)

[Cloud Foundry](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/)

[Jelastic](http://jelastic.com)

Besides, the costs depend on the application resources. In Jelastic [VDS](http://jelastic.com/docs/vds) is also scaled vertically. So there is no fixed imposed price for this.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the question was asked years ago, I think it might still be useful for others.

I recommend trying Jelastic Cloud, as they provide unique vertical auto scaling (in addition to horizontal as well), for Java, PHP, Go, Ruby, Python, Node.js projects hosting and for Docker or Kubernetes containerized apps.

Jelastic platform is pretty easy to use, provides wide variety of prepackaged applications ready for install in 1 click, is famous for its revolutionary Pay-per-Use approach that lets you pay only for resources in use (without huge overpaying like twice bigger VMs packages in AWS), auto scalability that enables your apps grow easily without a need to migrate/expect downtimes and much more great features.

Jelastic has Cloud partners across the globe, and in Australia Cloudlets.com.au could be mentioned with Tier III data center, providing a first class cloud hosting services and good technical support.